# Custom View works bad on tablets

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have custom View which is added to android.R.id.content in Activity.
On phones and some tablets it works properly but on 10 inch screen tablets it's lagging and working unexpectedly.

Initialization and calling view:

```
SlideDialog slideDialog = new SlideDialog(MyActivity.this, editText);
    slideDialog.setOnDismissSlideDialog(this);
    slideDialog.showDialog();
    getSupportFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(slideDialog.getContentId(),new MyFragment()).commit;
```

This View contains two class, one Interface and one XML file.
Here is

### OnDismissSlideDialog

```
public interface OnDismissSlideDialog {
  void dismiss();
}
```

### SlideDialogClass

```
public class SlideDialog implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        SlideLayout.OnSlideHeightChangeListener,
        SlideLayout.OnRemove,
        ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

      private static final String LOG_TAG = Logger.getLogTag(SlideDialog.class);

      private static final Float BASE_SHADOW = 0.5f;

      private Activity activity;
      private Context context;
      private ViewGroup rootView;
      private SlideLayout content;
      private LinearLayout contentRoot;
      private OnDismissSlideDialog onDismissSlideDialog;
      private EditText editText;

      public SlideDialog(Activity activity, @Nullable EditText editText) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.context = activity.getApplicationContext();
        this.editText = editText;
        initDialog();
      }

      public void showDialog() {
        content.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        showContentRoot();
        if (editText != null) {
          InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context.getSystemService(
              Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
          inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
      }

      public void setOnDismissSlideDialog(OnDismissSlideDialog onDismissSlideDialog) {
        this.onDismissSlideDialog = onDismissSlideDialog;
      }

      public int getContentId() {
        return content.getContentId();
      }

      private void showContentRoot() {
        rootView.addView(contentRoot);
        slideInContent();
      }

      private void removeContentRootWithAnimation() {
        slideOutContent();
      }

      private void removeContentRoot() {
        rootView.removeView(contentRoot);
        setTransparentStatusBar(activity, context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        if (onDismissSlideDialog != null) {
          onDismissSlideDialog.dismiss();
        }
        activity = null;
      }

      private void slideInContent() {
        content.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(content, "translationY", rootView.getMeasuredHeight() / 2, 0);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(context.getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime));
        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(this);
        objectAnimator.start();
      }

      private void slideOutContent() {
        ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(content, "translationY", content.getTranslationY(), rootView.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
        objectAnimator.setDuration(context.getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime));
        objectAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        objectAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
          @Override
          public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            removeContentRoot();
          }

          @Override
          public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

          }

          @Override
          public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

          }
        });
        objectAnimator.addUpdateListener(this);
        objectAnimator.start();
      }

      private void initDialog() {
        View baseView = activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
        rootView = (ViewGroup) baseView.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        contentRoot = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.slide_dialog, null, false);
        content = (SlideLayout) contentRoot.findViewById(R.id.slide_content);
        content.setOnSlideHeightChangeListener(this);
        content.setRemoveListener(this);
        contentRoot.setOnClickListener(this);
        content.setOnClickListener(this);
      }

      private int adjustAlpha(int color, float factor) {
        int alpha = Math.round(Color.alpha(color) * factor);
        int red = Color.red(color);
        int green = Color.green(color);
        int blue = Color.blue(color);
        return Color.argb(alpha, red, green, blue);
      }

      private int darker(int color, float factor) {
        int a = Color.alpha(color);
        int r = Color.red(color);
        int g = Color.green(color);
        int b = Color.blue(color);

        return Color.argb(a,
            Math.max((int) (r * factor), 0),
            Math.max((int) (g * factor), 0),
            Math.max((int) (b * factor), 0));
      }

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == contentRoot.getId()) {
          dismissDialog();
        }
      }

      @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
      public void setTransparentStatusBar(Activity activity, int color) {
        if (activity != null) {
          if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            activity.getWindow().setStatusBarColor(color);
          }
        }
      }

      public void dismissDialog() {
        removeContentRootWithAnimation();
      }

      @Override
      public void onHeightChange(int currentHeight, int maxHeight) {
        float alpha = (float) ((currentHeight * 100) / maxHeight) / 100;
        contentRoot.setBackgroundColor(adjustAlpha(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black), alpha));
        setTransparentStatusBar(activity, darker(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark), 1 - alpha));
      }

      @Override
      public void onRemove() {
        removeContentRoot();
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        Float value = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        if (content.getMeasuredHeight() > 0) {
          value = ((value * 100) / content.getMeasuredHeight()) / 100;
          value = (value / 2 + BASE_SHADOW);
          contentRoot.setBackgroundColor(adjustAlpha(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black), 1 - value));
          setTransparentStatusBar(activity, darker(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark), value));
        }
      }
    }
```

### SlideLayout

```
public class SlideLayout extends LinearLayout implements View.OnTouchListener {

  private static final String LOG_TAG = Logger.getLogTag(SlideLayout.class);

  private static final int VELOCITY_UNIT = 200;
  private static final int MAX_VELOCITY = 1000;
  private static final int SHORT_ANIMATION = 175;

  private VelocityTracker mVelocityTracker = null;
  private OnSlideHeightChangeListener onSlideHeightChangeListener;
  private OnRemove removeListener;
  private boolean isMeasured = false;
  private int height;
  private int rootHeight;
  private int coordinateMoveY;
  private int coordinateDownY;
  private float velocity;
  private boolean isAnimated = false;
  private FrameLayout container;

  @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
  public SlideLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    init(context);
  }

  public SlideLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
  }

  public SlideLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
  }

  public SlideLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
  }

  public void init(Context context) {
    setOrientation(VERTICAL);

    ImageView slidePanel = new ImageView(context);
    container = new FrameLayout(context);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams containerParams  = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
    );

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams slidePanelParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
      container.setId(generateViewId());
    } else {
      container.setId(android.R.id.custom);
    }

    container.setLayoutParams(containerParams);
    slidePanel.setLayoutParams(slidePanelParams);

    slidePanel.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    slidePanel.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_lines);

    addView(slidePanel);
    addView(container);
    slidePanel.setOnTouchListener(this);
  }

  public int getContentId() {
    return container.getId();
  }

  @Override
  public void setTranslationY(float translationY) {
    super.setTranslationY(translationY);
  }

  public void setOnSlideHeightChangeListener(OnSlideHeightChangeListener onSlideHeightChangeListener) {
    this.onSlideHeightChangeListener = onSlideHeightChangeListener;
  }

  public void setRemoveListener(OnRemove removeListener) {
    this.removeListener = removeListener;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (!isMeasured) {
      if (getMeasuredHeight() > height) {
        height = getMeasuredHeight();
          rootHeight = (height * 2);
      }
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);
  }

  private void setHeight(int coordinateY) {
    setLayoutParams(
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                coordinateY)
        )
    );
  }

  private void slideToEnd(final int fromY, int toY, int velocity) {
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(fromY, 0);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(velocity);
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        isAnimated = true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        isAnimated = false;
        removeListener.onRemove();
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

      }
    });
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        setTranslationY(fromY - value);
        onSlideHeightChangeListener.onHeightChange(value, rootHeight);
      }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();
  }

  private void slideToUp(int fromY, int toY, int velocity) {
    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(fromY, toY);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(velocity);
    valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    valueAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
        isAnimated = true;
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        isAnimated = false;
      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

      }
    });
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
      @Override
      public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        setHeight(value);
        onSlideHeightChangeListener.onHeightChange(value, rootHeight);
      }
    });
    valueAnimator.start();
  }

  private int measureCoordinateY(float rawCoordinateY) {
    int measuredCoordinateY;
    if (rawCoordinateY > 0) {
      measuredCoordinateY = getMeasuredHeight() - (int) (rawCoordinateY);
    } else {
      measuredCoordinateY = getMeasuredHeight() + (int) (Math.abs(rawCoordinateY));
    }

    return measuredCoordinateY;
  }

  private int getAnimationDuration(float velocity) {
    int animationSpeedDifference =
        getResources()
            .getInteger(android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime) - SHORT_ANIMATION;

    return (int) (getResources()
        .getInteger(android.R.integer.config_longAnimTime) - (velocity / MAX_VELOCITY) * animationSpeedDifference);
  }

  public interface OnSlideHeightChangeListener {
    void onHeightChange(int currentHeight, int maxHeight);
  }

  public interface OnRemove {
    void onRemove();
  }

  public int getStatusBarHeight() {
    int result = 0;
    int resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    if (resourceId > 0) {
      result = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int index = event.getActionIndex();
    int pointerId = event.getPointerId(index);

    if (!isAnimated) {
      switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          if (mVelocityTracker == null) {
            mVelocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
          } else {
            mVelocityTracker.clear();
          }
          coordinateDownY = measureCoordinateY(event.getY());
          mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
          isMeasured = true;
          break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
          if (coordinateMoveY != 0) {
            if (coordinateDownY < coordinateMoveY) {
              slideToUp(coordinateMoveY, rootHeight, getAnimationDuration(velocity));
            } else {
              slideToEnd(coordinateMoveY, 0, getAnimationDuration(velocity));
            }
          }
          return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          coordinateMoveY = measureCoordinateY(event.getY());
          setHeight(coordinateMoveY);

          if (coordinateMoveY < 0) {
            removeListener.onRemove();
          }

          onSlideHeightChangeListener.onHeightChange(coordinateMoveY, rootHeight);

          mVelocityTracker.addMovement(event);
          mVelocityTracker.computeCurrentVelocity(VELOCITY_UNIT, MAX_VELOCITY);

          velocity = Math.abs(VelocityTrackerCompat.getYVelocity(mVelocityTracker, pointerId));
          return true;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
          mVelocityTracker.recycle();
          break;
      }
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
  }
}
```

### XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/decor_content_parent"
              xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

  <Space
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <SlideLayout
      android:id="@+id/slide_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="@color/white">
  </SlideLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```